# Webview tag not working for my chrome app

Tags: javascript, html, webview, google-chrome-app

So I have been trying to load google in my app using this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webview</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Kitanga Nday">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon.png">
    <script src="kng.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="kontainer"> <!-- Kontainer div -->
        <webview src="https://www.google.com/" width="640" height="480"></webview>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I then tried sandboxing the page and running it in the main html file using the iframe tag still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed the fact that using `<webview>` requires a `"webview"` [permission in the manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions).